# Get timestamp from datetime field in pandas only for notnull values

Tags: python, pandas, date, timestamp

I am trying to separate time component from datefield which are not null as below, but getting  error "ValueError: NaTType does not support timestamp"

```
np.where(df1['Date'].isnull(),' ', pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']).apply(lambda a: a.timestamp()))
```

what could be the issue, please help

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `.dt.date` and `.dt.time` to extract the date and time parts, which can handle null values automatically for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['2018-10-10 09:10:00', None]})
df.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime)

df['Date'] = df.DateTime.dt.date
df['Time'] = df.DateTime.dt.time
df
#             DateTime        Date      Time
#0 2018-10-10 09:10:00  2018-10-10  09:10:00
#1                 NaT         NaT       NaT
```

Or if you are specifically looking for the timestamp, move the null check into `apply`, since `np.where` doesn't prevent `NaT` from calling `.timestamp` method, instead it does a post filtering:

```
df.DateTime.apply(lambda x: x.timestamp() if pd.notnull(x) else x)
#0    1.53916e+09
#1            NaT
#Name: DateTime, dtype: object
```